# Calculating Employee Headcount per month in PowerPivot

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I've searched all over for an answer to this but nothing quite seems to match  what I need OR it doesn't work for me :(

I'm trying to calculate the number of employees (using an FTE numeric field - not just counting rows) per month.

My data is currently:

Master Worker table: Employee ID (unique), Start Date, Termination Date.

Calendar table.

There is a relationship between Master Worker and Calendar on Hire Date (not sure this is right though).

I have tried:

```
Workers employed:=VAR currentDate =
    MAX ( 'DimDate'[Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ('Master Worker'),
        FILTER (
            'Master Worker',
            ('Master Worker'[Start Date USE]<= currentDate
                && 'Master Worker'[Termination Date USE] >= currentDate )
                        )
    )
```

But this returns what looks like the people who started (i.e. with Start Dates) in the relevant month when sliced on the front end.

What I need as an output is a table that I can slice by month (or put on a chart with a month and year axis) that shows the total number of employees employed in that period - not hires or terminations.

I'm totally at a loss here nothing seems to be working! Any help greatly appreciated! :)

editing to add: This output would be great in a separate table if possible if a measure isn't possible:

| Date | Total FTE |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 2500 |
| 01/02/2022 | 2510 |
| 01/03/2022 | 2505 |
| 01/04/2022 | 2501 |
| 01/05/2022 | 2500 |
| 01/06/2022 | 2530 |
| 01/07/2022 | 2532 |
| 01/08/2022 | 2501 |
| 01/09/2022 | 2501 |
| 01/10/2022 | 2500 |
| 01/11/2022 | 2530 |
| 01/12/2022 | 2510 |
| 01/01/2023 | 2505 |
| 01/02/2023 | 2501 |

Comment: `@kcoco` Would a pivot-table based approach work for you? Or do you only want answers limited to the PowerPivot environment?

Comment: Hiya - Yes I would be happy for it to be pivot table based i.e. on the front end of the data set as ultimately this is what it's for :) I just can't get it to pull out that way. It does need to be from this data set in this file though so my assumption is that at the very least a measure is needed :/

Answer (score 0):

Your relationship is based on hire on date which is the trick here since it might be sufficient to calculate employment status by month indirectly without a direct relationship for this calculation. I would go for manipulating the calendar table and looping over months while filtering based on the conditions. (try to review your relationship)

Try to update your measure like below :

```
Employees Employed:= 
VAR currentDate = MAX('Calendar'[Date])
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Master Worker'[FTE]), 
        FILTER(
            'Master Worker', 
            'Master Worker'[Start Date] <= currentDate && 
            (ISBLANK('Master Worker'[Termination Date]) || 'Master Worker'[Termination Date] >= currentDate)
        )
    )
```

---

```
Active Employees:=
VAR currentDate = MAX('Calendar'[Date])
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        SUMX(
            'Master Worker',
            IF(
                'Master Worker'[Start Date] <= currentDate &&
                'Master Worker'[Termination Date] >= currentDate,
                1, // Assuming each row represents 1 FTE
                0
            )
        ),
        ALL('Calendar')
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help - I tried this but it returned Blank :(

What should the relationship be here? :

Comment: Can you please share your model ?

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to use `ALL` to remove the context from the relationship. Additionally, you'll need to cater for those who don't have a Termination date.

Try:

```
Workers employed:=
  var currentDate  = MAX ( 'DimDate'[Date] )

  return
    CALCULATE(
      COUNTROWS('Master Worker'),
      ALL('DimDate'),
      'Master Worker'[Start Date USE] <= currentDate &&
      (
        'Master Worker'[Termination Date USE] > currentDate ||
        ISBLANK('Master Worker'[Termination Date USE])
      )
    )
```

If you don't want to count rows, then replace `COUNTROWS('Master Worker')` with the following:

```
DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK('Master Worker'[Employee ID])
```

If you have a default termination date set way into the future (ie non-blank) then you can have:

```
Workers employed:=
  var currentDate  = MAX ( 'DimDate'[Date] )

  return
    CALCULATE(
      COUNTROWS('Master Worker'),
      ALL('DimDate'),
      'Master Worker'[Start Date USE] <= currentDate &&
      'Master Worker'[Termination Date USE] > currentDate
    )
```

Alternative if `DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK` is not available.

```
Workers employed:=
  var currentDate  = MAX ( 'DimDate'[Date] )

  return
    CALCULATE(
      COUNTROWS(DISTINCT('Master Worker'[Employee ID])),
      ALL('DimDate'),
      'Master Worker'[Start Date USE] <= currentDate,
      'Master Worker'[Termination Date USE] > currentDate
    )
```

Comment: I've added in termination dates of never (i.e. 31/12/2154) for those that don't have one :) - do I need to amend your formula here for that?

Comment: You can keep it as is (won't do any harm), or you can simplify it with the second one in the updated answer above.

Comment: Thank you - unfortunately it doesn't recognise the removefilters function :/ It says it is not a valid function name. Do you know if there is an alternative? I am assuming that this is available only in certain versions of excel :(

Comment: Apologies, different versions of Excel don't have all the DAX functions. Use `ALL` instead, answer updated above.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but this comes back as an error too! "The expression contains multiple columns, but only a single column can be used in a True/false expression that is used as a table filter expression." 

:/ unfortunately it also doesn't recognise DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK as a function!

Comment: Tyt the last variation in the answer above.